# Recuperar los valores del los campos al volver atras en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando *laravel 5.4* estoy validando el formulario con el `Valitador:make`, lo que quiero saber es que al momento de ocurrir una falla y volver atrás pudiera volver a mostrar el valor que tenia los campos antes de recargar la pagina, en lugar que salgan los `input` vacíos.

Este es el codigo que uso para la validaciones en el controlador de usuario al momento de ingresar un nuevo usuario

```
$messages = [
        'unique' => 'El :attribute ya existe',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
    ], $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
       return redirect('users')->withErrors($validator, 'SaveUser')->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código de la validación y el formulario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque puede faltar un poco de información para enfocar mejor el contexto, en general si quieres mostrar los valores ingresados debes agregar el helper `{{ old('campo') }}` al value del campo:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre') }}">
```

Puedes encontrar más información en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-old